# "Печь" и "печаль"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Это снова я с однокоренными словами. Сейчас интересует "печь" и "печаль" - общее ли у них происхождение?

Comment: вам пора бы уже и рассказать чего-нибудь, не только спрашивать.
Столько же источников вокруг.

Comment: А объясните мне, зачем здесь задавать такие вопросы, на которые ответ находиться весьма просто? Просто нужно открыть словарик...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**ПЕЧАЛЬ**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Происходит праслав. формы *реčаlь (из *реkēlь), от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. печаль (λύπη, θλῖψις; Остром., Супр.), русск. печаль, укр., белор. печа́ль, болг. печа́л, словенск. реčа̑l «скорбь, грусть», отсюда печа́литься, печа́ловаться, др.-русск. печаловатися. Связ. с печь, пеку. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

[**ПЕЧЬ**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C)

Происходит от праслав. формы *реktь, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. печь, ст.-слав. пешть (κάμινος, σπήλαιον), русск. печь, укр. пiч (род. п. пе́чи), белор. печ, болг. пещ, сербохорв. пе̑ħ (род. п. пе̏ħи, словенск. ре̑č (род. п. реčȋ, чешск., словацк. рес, польск. рiес (м.), в.-луж. рjес, н.-луж. рjас. Праслав. *реktь : пеку́; ср. др.-инд. paktíṣ ж. «варка, вареное кушанье», греч. πέψις ж. «варка, жарение». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

**РЕЗЮМЕ**

Слова абсолютно несхожие и происхождение у них разное.